# Concat DataFrame under specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following dataframes which are stored in a list of lists, I want to `concat` them if there is something to:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

fr_list = [[] for x in range(2)]
fr_list[0].append(df1)
fr_list[0].append(df1)
fr_list[1].append(df1)

for x in range(2):
   df = pd.concat(fr_list[x] if len(fr_list[x]) > 1)  # <-- here is the problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you want is probably:

```
...
df = pd.concat((fr for fr in fr_list[x] if len(fr) > 1))
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: @ironzionlion did not realize that fr_list was a list of lists. Post edited